# Error Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user" when migrating

Tags: django, postgresql

I am running into this error when i migrate.Is there any way to save data on my database.I know that dropping the auth_user table will fix the issue. I am running postgresql.
Thanks!

```
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "api_poi" ADD CONSTRAINT "user_id_refs_id_20f256ff" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
The error was: insert or update on table "api_poi" violates foreign key constraint "user_id_refs_id_20f256ff"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user".
```

Comment: @Sagar I assume you have knowledge that the table contains no data that is needed since you suggest deleting everything from there? Would be helpful to mention that.

Comment: Dropping `auth_user` wouldn't help since you'd still have the table `api_poi` which is referencing the table. You can delete the rows that reference users not found in the database and then the constraint will succeed.

Comment: But by poi table has no rows that references users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a row in `api_poi` which has `user_id` set to 1, but there is no row in `auth_user` which has `id` set to 1.

So it is impossible to define a foreign key constraint like you are trying to do.

You will have to add rows to `auth_user` or remove rows from `api_poi` until the foreign key constraint is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Include `'django.contrib.admin',` in your INSTALLED_APP, then run migrations and migrate again.

Answer (score 0):

go to the database and insert code

```
ALTER SEQUENCE TableName_id_seq RESTART WITH 'last id number';
```

for example :

```
ALTER SEQUENCE account_id_seq RESTART WITH 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the very hardship. However, I had to flush all the data recorded in the database to avert this error as I didn't find any of the solutions given above helpful.

```
$ python manage.py flush
```

And confirmed yes.
I certainly would not recommend this way of bypassing integrity error if you care about the existing data in your DB coz it will nullify the table by omitting all the data outta the table.